# grep multiline pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, wget, multiline

I have a list of URLs in a file (each line = different Domain) I want to scan (not recursively) and pick two patterns, which are in different lines. After two days of trying - my head is spinning …

That is the important HTML-Part:

```
<a href="http://subdomain.domain.tld/">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-uv-trigger='true' href='mailto:john@doe.com'>
```

I need to pick the domain (subdomain.domain.tld) and the email-adress (john@doe.com). I can (wget / sed) the parts in two steps.

```
wget -O - -i urls-to-scan-manuell.txt | sed -n "s/\(.*a href=\"\)\(.*\)\(\">Home.*\)/\2/p"

wget -O - -i urls-to-scan-manuell.txt | sed -n "s/\(.*true' href='mailto\)\(.*\)\('>.*\)/\2/p"
```

But I would like to pick both parts at once and write them out to a file in one line, separated by a blank (space). It is the multiline thing with sed that drives me nuts.

Please: I need your help, would you :)

Thank you in advance,
Rainer.

Answer (score 2):

For the record: it's [not recommended to parse HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

---

You can use `sed` with multiple expressions with `-e` that could help here:

```
wget -O - -i urls-to-scan-manuell.txt | sed -n \
  -e "s/\(.*a href=\"\)\(.*\)\(\">Home.*\)/\2/p" \
  -e "s/\(.*true' href='mailto\)\(.*\)\('>.*\)/\2/p"
```

This will produce two lines, one for the domain and one for the email.
If you prefer the output on one line, you can pipe to `paste - -`. The default delimiter is TAB, you can change that with the `-d` flag, so for example:

```
wget -O - -i urls-to-scan-manuell.txt | sed -n \
  -e "s/\(.*a href=\"\)\(.*\)\(\">Home.*\)/\2/p" \
  -e "s/\(.*true' href='mailto:\)\(.*\)\('>.*\)/\2/p" | \
paste -d, - -
```

Will produce:

> ```
> http://subdomain.domain.tld/,john@doe.com
> ```

I took the liberty and added a `:` after `mailto` in the pattern,
because I guess that was your intention.

Comment: Arf, I forgot a pipe symbol `|` at the end of the `sed` and before the `paste`. Added it now, check my update.